# Some pages return "502 Bad Gateway" error

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker, reverse-proxy, bitnami

I just realized that certain links of my website lead to "502 Bad Gateway" error. For example, https://v2a.10studio.tech/10studio/auth/google, https://v2a.10studio.tech/auth/google, https://v2a.10studio.tech/10studio/auth/microsoft, https://v2a.10studio.tech/auth/microsoft. I'm pretty sure that those links worked several weeks ago, I don't know what happened.

The website https://v2a.10studio.tech/ is still working. https://v2a.10studio.tech/#/sign?next=/ contains the buttons clicking on which lead to the broken links.

Here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: staticfloat/nginx-certbot
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    environment:
      CERTBOT_EMAIL: chengtie@gmail.com
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
      - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
  10studio:
    image: bitnami/nginx:1.16
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./build:/app
      - ./default.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/default.conf:ro
      - ./configs/config.prod.js:/app/lib/config.js
    depends_on: 
    - frontend

volumes:
  letsencrypt:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: 10studio
```

And `conf.d/v2.conf`:

```
gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/jpeg image/png image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

upstream funfun {
   server www.funfun.io:443;
}


server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/v2a.10studio.tech/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/v2a.10studio.tech/privkey.pem;
    server_name v2a.10studio.tech;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "";
    
    
    location ~ /socialLoginSuccess {                                                                                            
        rewrite ^ '/#/socialLoginSuccess' redirect;
     }

    location ~ /auth/(.*) {                                                                                            
        proxy_pass  https://funfun/10studio/auth/$1?$query_string;
        proxy_set_header Host v2a.10studio.tech;
     }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          http://10studio:8080/;

        # These three lines added as per https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942 to remove socketio error
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Could anyone help?

PS: I changed some setting (especially SSL certificates) for funfun.io in CloudFlare several weeks ago, i don’t if it is related. I don't know if this `Proxy status` (`DNS only` or `Proxied`) has an impact.

[image]

**Edit 1:** here are some docker logs:

```
2020-08-18T20:19:15.667934708Z 2020/08/18 20:19:15 [error] 42#42: *310 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 176.144.215.193, server: v2a.10studio.tech, request: "GET /auth/github HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://104.27.153.135:443/10studio/auth/github?", host: "v2a.10studio.tech"
2020-08-18T20:19:15.667995550Z 2020/08/18 20:19:15 [warn] 42#42: *310 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 176.144.215.193, server: v2a.10studio.tech, request: "GET /auth/github HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://104.27.153.135:443/10studio/auth/github?", host: "v2a.10studio.tech"
2020-08-18T20:19:15.738088121Z 2020/08/18 20:19:15 [error] 42#42: *310 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 176.144.215.193, server: v2a.10studio.tech, request: "GET /auth/github HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://104.27.152.135:443/10studio/auth/github?", host: "v2a.10studio.tech"
2020-08-18T20:19:15.738135701Z 2020/08/18 20:19:15 [warn] 42#42: *310 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 176.144.215.193, server: v2a.10studio.tech, request: "GET /auth/github HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://104.27.152.135:443/10studio/auth/github?", host: "v2a.10studio.tech"
2020-08-18T20:19:15.803843403Z 2020/08/18 20:19:15 [error] 42#42: *310 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 176.144.215.193, server: v2a.10studio.tech, request: "GET /auth/github HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://172.67.193.92:443/10studio/auth/github?", host: "v2a.10studio.tech"
2020-08-18T20:19:15.803890220Z 2020/08/18 20:19:15 [warn] 42#42: *310 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 176.144.215.193, server: v2a.10studio.tech, request: "GET /auth/github HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://172.67.193.92:443/10studio/auth/github?", host: "v2a.10studio.tech"
2020-08-18T20:19:15.803908241Z 176.144.215.193 - - [18/Aug/2020:20:19:15 +0000] "GET /auth/github HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020-08-18T20:19:21.284333260Z 2020/08/18 20:19:21 [error] 42#42: *310 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 176.144.215.193, server: v2a.10studio.tech, request: "GET /10studio/auth/github HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://funfun/10studio/auth/github?", host: "v2a.10studio.tech"
2020-08-18T20:19:21.285121395Z 176.144.215.193 - - [18/Aug/2020:20:19:21 +0000] "GET /10studio/auth/github HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: Check the nginx error logs.

Comment: just added some logs in the OP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `SSL alert number 40` means you tried to connect to an HTTPS site which requires SNI but did not send a SNI hostname.

You are trying to `proxy_pass` requests that start with `/auth/` to an `upstream` server named `www.funfun.io`. But this site is hosted on CloudFlare and thus requires SNI to connect to it with HTTPS. Unfortunately nginx's SNI support for outgoing upstream HTTPS connections is disabled by default (I can't imagine why). You need to explicitly enable SNI for outgoing connections to upstream with `proxy_ssl_server_name on;`. This can be set in the `http` context so that it applies to every attempted `proxy_pass` in your entire configuration, or can be placed only in specific `location`s where it is needed.

Comment: So I put `proxy_ssl_server_name on;`  inside the block of `location ~ /auth/(.*)` of my `conf.d/v2.conf`?

Comment: @SoftTimur I already answered that. Is something unclear about the explanation?

Comment: Now, clicking on those links return `403 Forbidden cloudflare`...

Comment: @SoftTimur Well, you did override the hostname and send it one that it probably doesn't recognize. There's no indication of why you did that or what the purpose is. But at least the current problem with SSL is fixed. You might consider asking a new question, but you should think carefully about why are you doing this particular proxy pass in this way to begin with.

Comment: I set `upstream funfun { server 178.62.87.72:443; }` and add `proxy_ssl_name "www.funfun.io"; proxy_ssl_server_name on;` inside the server block and before `location`s. It is working now. Thank you.